# Почему не срабатывает условие? Помогите разобраться со значением NaN

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, y = NaN, но почему тогда условие выдает false? Или существуют два разных значения NaN?

Comment: ```Double.IsNaN(y)```

Comment: `NaN` - это `not a number`, его нельзя сравнивать обычным сравнением. Во всех языках его специальными функциями проверяют, а не через `==` сравнивают.

Comment: Значительно более интересный вопрос со смежной темы - как работает метод `IsNaN` внутри? https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/double.cs почему написанное работает? Что там происходит?

Comment: Кстати, полезно понимать, что `null` (или если в питоне, то `None`) - это не `NaN`, их можно сравнивать на равенство между собой и с не `null` значениями, это нормально работает.

Comment: NaN во всех логических операциях возвращает false. Такая задумка. Например NaN == NaN -> false. Среди значений вещественного типа это единственное, которое не равно себе. Это сюрприз для программиста и для многих алгоритмов (для сортировки например). Последствия обширны. Например, `a <= b` нельзя рефакторить в `!(a > b)` - поведение в случае NaN изменится. То есть, это не рефакторинг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NaN` это условность, означающая Not a Number, внутри класса (в данном случае double) она как-то описана и когда вы пишите `double.NaN` вы как раз пытаетесь вызвать это описание, но значение `у` есть NaN, а не описание NaN-а. Следовательно вы должны вызывать специальную функцию в классе double. Обычно она называется типа `isNan()` или подобным образом. В шарпе это `Double.IsNaN(y)`

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь подвести логику под `(NaN == NaN) == false`, то у вас не получится. Это произвольное решение авторов Intel 8087 и IEEE-774. Оно иногда полезно, но делает всю алгебру и логику вокруг вещественных чисел слегка кособокой. Написать алгоритм с учётом NaN, наверное, раза в три сложнее чем без него.